# How can I send context to Django in every page without sending from all the views

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, tags

I am trying to create an eCommerce app and have the cart option in that. However, on every page of the site (or every view), I always type the code...

```
context = {
        "no_in_cart":no_of_items_in_cart(request)
}
```

Where `no_of_items_in_cart` is a function to find the number of items in the cart.
But I feel this is a waste of code and may have several inefficiencies.
And also I am not sure on how I can send this code through `auth_views`, such as login or register views.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

**EDITED CONTENT**

So now in my tag_name.py I have the code..

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()


@register.inclusion_tag("base.html")
def a_tag_name(request):
    return {"no_in_cart":no_of_items_in_cart(request)}



def no_of_items_in_cart(request):
    total = 0
    for item in request.session.get('order'):
        total += item["quantity"]

    return (total)
```

And in my base.html I have the following tags at the very top of the page...

```
{% load static %}
{% load tag_name %} 
{% a_tag_name request %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
...
```

And I don't repeat the tags `{% load tag_name %}`  or `{% a_tag_name request %}` in any other sub-template.

However, by doing so, I am thrown with an error...

```
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:'str' object has no attribute 'session'
```

And it highlights the line `{% a_tag_name request %}`.

Any idea on how to figure this out?
Thanks!

Comment: If you have very few lines to write in a view then you can call a particular view by multiple urls and perform different tasks by fetching the url and then use if else.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question correctly. You are displaying the "no_in_cart" in many pages where you have to pass this context variables every time you render a page. You want to have a way where the context variable(no_in_cart) can be used in many pages but you do not have to pass it every time.
This can be done using template tags. Not sure if its efficient.
If you want I can give a sample code to work with template tags.

Create  Files as described below:-

```
Appdirectory
   templatetags
     __init__.py
     tag_name.py
   models.py
   views.py
```

In tag_name.py:-

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()


@register.inclusion_tag("condition.html")
def a_tag_name(request):
   return {"no_in_cart":no_of_items_in_cart(request)}
```

Then in condition.html:-

```
# some django template code(html) if required
{{no_in_cart}}
```

Then finally in the page where you want to use this.
At the top load the tags first

```
{% load tag_name %}
```

then put this the desired place
 `{% a_tag_name request %}`

Location of files should be as specified. You can rename everything except templatetags. Also run manage.py collectstatic.
Hope it helps.

If you want to learn more about tags refer:-
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-template-tags/

https://medium.com/@hiteshgarg14/creating-custom-template-tags-in-django-application-7bd1dcfeb144

Comment: Well, it didn't seem to work and I am not sure where I should place the `{% a_tag_name request %}` tag name, is it in my base template? or the subtemplates that extend from the base template.

Comment: You can put it in any template. Assume **a_tag_name** as a method which renders on **condition.html**.
When you use  {% a_tag_name request %} in any other template. you are calling a_tag_name with request args. and it returns django template code(html)  as defined in condition.html.
So it can be placed in base template.
If any errors please share.

Comment: I have edited my question with the error of what I am trying to explain.